# Apache camel XML route configuration - inherit common parameters

Tags: xml, configuration, apache-camel

Given that I have a legacy Camel application that is configured using XML, I have many routes that have common parameters.  E.g.

```
<camel:camelContext>
<camel:endpoint id=sampleEndpoint1" uri="user1@host.com/inbound?password=password1&amp;readLock=none&amp;delete=true&amp;include=.*.xml&amp;disconnect=false&amp;knownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts&amp;serverAliveInterval=30&amp;preferredAuthentications=password&amp;ciphers=arcfour128,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr"/>

<camel:endpoint id=sampleEndpoint2" uri="user2@host.com/inbound?password=password2&amp;readLock=none&amp;delete=true&amp;include=.*.xml&amp;disconnect=false&amp;knownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts&amp;serverAliveInterval=30&amp;preferredAuthentications=password&amp;ciphers=arcfour128,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr"/>

<camel:endpoint id=sampleEndpoint3" uri="user3@host.com/inbound?password=password3&amp;readLock=none&amp;delete=true&amp;include=.*.xml&amp;disconnect=false&amp;knownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts&amp;serverAliveInterval=30&amp;preferredAuthentications=password&amp;ciphers=arcfour128,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```

After the **password** parameter all the remaining parameters in the route definitions are the same.

Is there a way for routes to inherit common parameters in a similar fashion to Spring bean configuration where you can inherit properties from a **parent** bean?

Comment: Why not add the additional parameters as properties in the context definition and then use it in your endpoints: like this `uri=user2@${additionalParameters}`. If you are interested in this solution I could complete it in an answer.

Comment: I had already thought of this. I was hoping there was a more "idiomatic" way.